# Bulk load permissions

Tags: sql-server

I have server rrp-graph with installed SQL Server 2008 R2 instance which runs from Local System account.

[image]

I have another server rrp-garchive with shared folder. I'm sorry for russian language, it says that I granted full access to folder to rrp-graph computer.

[image]

[image]

Ok, now I want to BULK insert a file from shared folder (on server rrp-garchive) to table on server rrp-graph. I do:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tREL_IUAttributes4IULog_BLOB WITH (TABLOCK) (IULog_ID, AttributeIULog_ID, Value, OrderPos)  
    SELECT 1, 30, rs.BulkColumn, 1 FROM 
    OPENROWSET(BULK N'\\rrp-garchive\KSPDImagesBaseTest\12\15\00\12150014.tif', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
```

But I receive following error:

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "\\rrp-garchive\KSPDImagesBaseTest\12\15\00\12150014.tif" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
```

What else should I do to be able to do bulk operations. Thanks.

Comment: As a test have you tried to copy file over to local system and try it again?

Comment: I tried that and it worked just ok from local disk.

Comment: have you tried to map the network drive?

Comment: Now he even doesn't see that location: Operating system error code 3